# (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, module, fetch

When i run my app on FireFox, the console returns me an error : (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

I understand what's that mean but i have no clue how to fix it. Besides everythings run well on the others browsers...( chrome, Edge ..)
anyone has an idea?

here my code :

```
export function fetchManager(url, data) {

    // Objet littéral des paramètres
    const options= {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method:'POST',
        header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
    // Appel et récupère le retour de fetch
    let reponseData = fetch(url, options)
    
    return reponseData;
}
```

And here the return of the Firefox's console :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Thank you all.

I try to check firefox's setting but without success..

Comment: When you open the Network tab of Firefox's DevTools, then click on `All` option, do you see any blocked resources?